# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, variables, type-conversion

I'm a beginner running through some easy enough challenges, and I can't seem to figure out this issue. Code is just a function for finding the biggest and smallest numbers in an array, and even if this isn't exactly an efficient way to do it, I have no idea where the code is getting an int from. Anyone able to shed light on that?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Program 
{
    public static double[] FindMinMax(double[] values) 
    {

        double small = values.Min();
        double big = values.Max();

        double result = new double[small, big];

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have no idea where the code is getting an int from

You are asking, here (`new double[small, big]`) for it to create a 2-dimensional (rectangular) array with dimensions (for example) 17.2 × 42.6 - it is those dimensions that it wants to be integers.

---

I think you mean to create a vector (single-dimension zero-based array) with the two values as the *contents*:

```cs
double[] result = new double[] {small, big};
```

Although I suspect a value-tuple would work more effectively, i.e.

```cs
public static (double Min, double Max) FindMinMax(double[] values) 
{
    // ...
    return (small, big);
}
```

You might also want to look into whether it is optimal (it might not be) to write an explicit single loop that checks min and max both in each step, rather than two iterations. But as long as the data isn't *huge*, it won't matter at all. And if it *is* huge, then you get into topics like sharding the array and performing parallel min/max on the different shards, and then aggregating the shard results. There may also be SIMD options here.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got so caught up in the conversion that I didn't realise how  much I was messing up on array basics. Cheers for clearing that up, might try the loop method later too. Mainly just focused on learning right now